# Error while splitting application context file in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to split the ApplicationContext file in Spring.

For ex. the file is testproject-servlet.xml having all the entries. Now I want to split this single file into multiple files according to logical groups like :
group1-services.xml, group2-services.xml

I have created following entries in web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testproject</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/group1-services.xml, /WEB-INF/group2-services.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I am using SimpleUrlHandlerMapping as:

```
<bean id="simpleUrlMapping"class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
    <property name="mappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="/register.htm">RegisterController</prop>             <prop key="/payroll_services.htm">PayrollServicesController</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I also have the controller defined as :

```
<bean id="PayrollServicesController" class="com.triforce.b2bseek.businessservices.controller.PayrollServicesController">
      <property name="facadeLookup" ref="FacadeLookup"/>
      ..
      ..
      </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is that I have splitted the ApplicationContext file "testproject-servlet.xml" into two different files and I have kept the above entries in "group1-services.xml". Is it fine? I want to group things logically based on their use in seperate .xml files.

But I am getting the following error when I try to access a page inside the application :

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for [/TestProject/payroll_services.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'testproject'
```

Please tell me how to resolve it.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: missing essential configuration samples

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

                /WEB-INF/group1-services.xml, /WEB-INF/group2-services.xml

with

/WEB-INF/group1-services.xml
/WEB-INF/group2-services.xm

Hope this will work...:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a problem with your `contextConfigLocation` as such

I think its more that the dispatcher needs to know where to send `payroll_servives.htm` to, and can't find an appropriate handler knowing what to do with this pattern.

See [reference documentation](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-servlet)

***Did you really want `*.htm` files to be matched to the dispatcher servlet?***

If you are using annotation-based controllers (`@Controller`), then you need to have a line similar to:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web"/>
```

This installs an appropriate annotation-based handler, that searchs for classes/methods annotated like:

```
@Controller
public class PayrollController {
     @RequestMapping("payroll_services.htm")
     public ModelAndView payrollServices() {
         ....
     }
}
```

Otherwise, if you are using more traditional handlers/controllers, you need to define this using XML. The reference documentation link earlier in this posting mentions two such handlers: `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` or `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`

Perhaps if you updated your question with snippets of handler/controller XML, this may help?

Comment: Thanks for your help
I have updated my question with more details.. please help on it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the ContextLoaderListener to your web.xml?  I don't see it:

```
   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
```

Comment: Yes I have this entry in web.xml. Still I am getting the error.

I am not able to figure it out why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include something like this in each of your files:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao" />
```

If it is missing from a file, it seems the annotated classes are not known in the context of that file.

You may want to revisit the [documentation](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Either the handler mapping of your DispatcherServlet is incorrect or you're using the wrong url. If you fix the layout around your SimpleUrlHandlerMapping configuration I can tell you what to change.